# How to display loading.gif at the center of the screen which has a scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to display loading.gif/spinning wheel whenever a user clicks the button.
I have added a div as below in the master page:

```
<div id="loadingDiv">
    <div>
        <h7>Please wait...</h7>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the css:

```
#loadingDiv{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#666;
  background-image:url('ajax-loader.gif');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  z-index:10000000;
  opacity: 0.4;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

When I try this, the loading.gif is displayed at the center of the page. But as the page is really long , I have to scroll in order to see the loading.gif.

How can I display the loading.gif at the center of the screen which is visible?
And if I scroll down, I should see that again at the center of the screen.

Comment: Try `position:fixed`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

in your CSS, try changing position:absolute; with position:fixed;

Answer (score 38):

Here's the solution. .  [JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ankitsnghn/P8dne/1/)

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="content">
    Long Content Here
    <br/>
    Click to view loading image.
</div>
<div id="divLoading"> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
#divLoading
{
display : none;
}
#divLoading.show
{
display : block;
position : fixed;
z-index: 100;
background-image : url('http://loadinggif.com/images/image-selection/3.gif');
background-color:#666;
opacity : 0.4;
background-repeat : no-repeat;
background-position : center;
left : 0;
bottom : 0;
right : 0;
top : 0;
}
#loadinggif.show
{
left : 50%;
top : 50%;
position : absolute;
z-index : 101;
width : 32px;
height : 32px;
margin-left : -16px;
margin-top : -16px;
}
div.content {
width : 1000px;
height : 1000px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div.content").click(function(){
    $("div#divLoading").addClass('show');
});
});
```

Answer (score 13):

I used to have this html and css and it always display in center whether my page is long or short:

```
<div id="divLoading" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: fixed; right: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgb(102, 102, 102); z-index: 30001; opacity: 0.8;">
<p style="position: absolute; color: White; top: 50%; left: 45%;">
Loading, please wait...
<img src="images/ajax-loading.gif">
</p>
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ewNkK/)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
#loadingDiv{position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#666;background-image:url('ajax-loader.gif'); background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;z-index:10000000;  opacity: 0.4;
```

To:

```
#loadingDiv{position:fixed;top:0px;right:0px;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#666;background-image:url('ajax-loader.gif'); background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;z-index:10000000;  opacity: 0.4;
```

Changed `position` from `absolute` to `fixed`

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k67Zk/)**